# will a shutdown of a worker process for pool a affect pool b

Tags: windows, iis, performance, application-pools, iis-10

I have two pools running on the same server.
I noticed one of them is configured to a 20 min idle timeout, and the other is 180 mins.

I can see this message in event viewer:
"A worker process with process id of '1964' serving application pool 'A' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed."

Is that going to affect pool B? I had a skim through the logs and can't see the same message for pool B.
I assume both pools use the same worker process, or is that not the case.
Thanks

Comment: "both pools use the same worker process" is impossible. Starting from IIS 6, application pools are introduced for isolation, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/#overview

Comment: @LexLi ok thanks that's really good to know, and will help me narrow down what might be going on. I suspect the IIS worker process becomes unresponsive now and then. Thanks

Comment: IIS worker processes are simply web application containers. So if you find such processes do not respond to incoming requests, the common cause is your web apps. Guides like https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs can get you started.